# A sql query runs fine on windows but gives error on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(n.nid), n.title, n.type, n.status, n.moderate, n.teaser, e.event_start
FROM node n INNER JOIN
     node_access na
     ON na.nid = n.nid INNER JOIN
     event e
     USING (nid)
 WHERE ((na.grant_view = 1) AND
        CONCAT(na.realm, na.gid) IN ('all0','term_access1')) AND
        n.status = 1 AND n.moderate = 0 AND e.event_start >= 1400558400
 ORDER BY event_start;
```

it runs fine on windows mysql 4.1.22-community-nt but on ubuntu  5.5.24  it gives the below error:

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'nid' in from clause is ambiguous
```

Any idea why it could be happening? Assuming I can't change the query as it's run from an open source project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `from` clause:

```
FROM node n INNER JOIN
     node_access na
     ON na.nid = n.nid INNER JOIN
     event e
     USING (nid)
```

The error is saying that the engine doesn't know if `nid` is coming from `node` or `node_access`.  If you could change the query, you could do one of the following:

```
FROM node n INNER JOIN
     node_access na
     USING (nid) INNER JOIN
     event e
     USING (nid)
```

or

```
FROM node n INNER JOIN
     node_access na
     ON na.nid = n.nid INNER JOIN
     event e
     ON na.nid = e.nid
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the answer however like I said before in my question, I cannot change the query as its a third party module. Is there a way by which a setting on mysql can be done to ensure it falls to older version of SQL standard for the session/connection?